# C# Format exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 tables `Conturi` and `Persoana` and I want to show every single item that Cont has(I can't use a `ListView`) while doing this I run into a little problem.

The table looks like this:

```
[Cont]:
        - id (cheie primara)
        - id_persoana (cheie externa in [Persoana])
        - Banca (sir de caractere maxim 64)
        - Sold (decimal)
        - Unitate (moneda, sir de caracatere de lungime 3)
        - Data_deschiderii (data)
```

I am having trouble figuring out where my format exception is this is the code :

```
namespace TarnaLucianFlorinGrupa333
{
    public partial class Conturi : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = GetQuery();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            FillTable(reader);
            conn.Close();
        }


        private string GetQuery()
        {
            string query = string.Empty;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                query = string.Format("select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where c.Sold>={0} and p.Id = c.id_persoana", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
            }

            else
            {
                query = "select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where p.Id = c.id_persoana";
            }

            return query;
        }

        private void FillTable(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            TableRow th = Table1.Rows[0];
            Table1.Rows.Clear();
            Table1.Rows.Add(th);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();

                TableCell nume = new TableCell();
                nume.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(nume);

                TableCell Banca = new TableCell();
                Banca.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(Banca);

                TableCell Sold = new TableCell();
                Sold.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(Sold);

                TableCell Unitate = new TableCell();
                Unitate.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(Unitate);

                TableCell Data_Deschiderii = new TableCell();
                Data_Deschiderii.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(Data_Deschiderii);

                TableCell Adauga = new TableCell();
                Adauga.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"Adauga.aspx?id={0}\"> Adauga </a>", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                row.Cells.Add(Adauga);

                Table1.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }


    }
}
```

And this is the view:

```
   <table>

    <tr>
        <td> Soldul </td>
        <td> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td> 
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

          <td>

              <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Cauta" />

          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow BackColor=Aqua>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell> nume </asp:TableHeaderCell> 
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell> Banca </asp:TableHeaderCell> 
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell> Sold </asp:TableHeaderCell> 
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell> Unitate </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell> Data_Deschidere</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell> Adauga</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </td>


    </tr>

 </table>
```

The error that it throws me is :

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Could someone point me where this error is from ?

Comment: On which line exactly? On `Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)`?

Comment: this is everything that it tells me , I whish I knew... then i would probably be able to fix it...:( at troubleshooting there is a link with Datetime in it but i don't see why that would be

Comment: That definitely is not all that it tells you.

Comment: @LucianTarna Oh come on. Did you try to debug your code? If you do, it stops on line what throws exception. And you can see your local variable values inside of it.

Comment: not really I had to do a pretty big application in 90 min so I didn't have the time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TryParse` instead of this line. If the text in textbox is not a number, you will get `FormatException`.

```
Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: actually this worked :)) this is the right answer , problem is solved

Comment: @LucianTarna What worked exactly? You wrote `Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)` already in your code. o.O And `TryParse` returns `bool` but `Convert.ToInt32` returns `int` and seems your query expect it as `int`.

Comment: int id;
            Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out id); and voila instead od that Convert:D

Comment: @danish: You should elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

may be you have to to

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                query = string.Format("select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where c.Sold>={0} and p.Id = c.id_persoana", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
            }
```

seems you trying to convert to int when the textbox is empty

Comment: Open for `SQL Injection` attack.

Comment: Yes:P i did write that in my application with ! but when i copy pasted it , it seems that i lost the ! somehow

Answer (score 1):

Switch the `string.IsNullOrEmtpy()` with `int.TryParse(string, out int)` which returns true if the value was parsed. (or just stick to string.IsNullOrEmpty() if you don't want/need parsing)

```
    private string GetQuery()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        int value = -1;
        if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out value))
        {
            query = string.Format("select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where c.Sold>={0} and p.Id = c.id_persoana", value);
        }

        else
        {
            query = "select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where p.Id = c.id_persoana";
        }

        return query;
    }
```

As a side note you should look into parameterized queries rather than using `string.Format()` or even manual string concatenation.

Parameterized version:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = GetQuery();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        FillTable(reader);
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }

    private SqlCommand GetQuery()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        int value = -1;
        if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out value))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where c.Sold>=@Sold and p.Id = c.id_persoana";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sold", value));
        }

        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where p.Id = c.id_persoana";
        }

        return cmd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have placed wrong check for textbox. You are checking that if
>   value of TextBox1 is NULL or Empty than convert it to int32 so how a
>   null or empty value can be converted to int32.

Also make sure than integer value is being written in this textbox. Change it like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
{
query = string.Format("select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where c.Sold>={0} and p.Id = c.id_persoana", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));

}
else
 {
query = "select c.id,p.Nume, c.Banca,c.Sold,c.Unitate,c.Data_Deschiderii from Cont c,Persoana p where p.Id = c.id_persoana";                            
}
```

Comment: You need to invert the test **or** switch the if/else statements - if you do *both*, as you have here, you've just moved the bug.